# Email CSS - Grid of items, with different heights. (No JS, No CSS3, etc.)

Tags: html, css

I have some text, then a sections of items (variable number of items, and each is a variable height.)

Luckily I dont care about the order the items appears. What I do care about, it that there are not big gaps.

What I dont want is this:

[image]

What I want is this:

[image]

Important:

This is for an email!! So please, I know I can do this with JS, I know about Masonry.js, but that won't help me now. I need it to work for most email providers(not worried about complete coverage). So I think with the limited support of CSS in emails, I'm mostly limited to tables. Any idea how to acheive this look?

Comment: You could use a table with 2 columns and in each column use div's.

Answer (score 1):

Just like @nocturns2 says, it is possible to achieve this using a table, 2 columns and using divs for each block.

```css
.size1 {
  height: 100px;
}

.size2 {
  height: 150px; 
}

.size3 {
  height: 75px; 
}

div {
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 2px;
}

td {
  vertical-align: top; 
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="size1"></div>
      <div class="size1"></div>
      <div class="size2"></div>
      <div class="size3"></div>
      <div class="size1"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="size2"></div>
      <div class="size2"></div>
      <div class="size3"></div>
      <div class="size1"></div>      
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```